# Web Scraping Using Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js

I watched and tested tutorials and examples to help me understand how the scraping code works, I've seen Node.js and PHP tutorials, but sadly none of these tutorials explain how to actually connect this code to the `<input>`tag in html, so when the user paste the link, it scrape and display the data.
Like this guy explained here...but he didn't actually show how to connect this with html...Need a big help!!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wo5eMclb-G4
Skip to 1:05 to see what I really NEED to learn.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-node-js-request-and-cheerio-to-set-up-simple-web-scraping

Comment: Ok, cool! but What I really want to know is...how to link that code....with <input>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way:
STEP 1

1. create a node.js and express based app(website), and preferably with EJS base(EJS is not required but it makes everything easier).
2. on index.ejs file create a form field and place an input field inside the form field.
3. You can then get the value of input value by using "req.body"

STEP2

1. Create your web scraper based on "puppeteer"
2. Put your webscraper code and input form code inside the same express route.
3. When you create a web scraper with "puppeteer", you'll see there is url variable that you need to define. You can set the variable value to "req.body" value and it is done.
   Don't hesitate to comment down for any clarification.